# Why i am not able to delete one more CollectionVIew Cell with JSON parameter in swift?

Tags: json, swift, uicollectionview

IN my viewcontroller i have two JSON APIs 1) for adding image and title to collectionView cell and 2) for deleting the cell

with my below code **i am able to delete only one cell first time, if i try to delete another cell i am unable to delete,.. i am getting json validation error, why?.. i want to delete selected cell any time..**

this is my first JSON API response : for adding image and title to collectionview... with this respective `pic_id` i need to remove the cell.. in my second JSON API

```
  {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "image": {
        "image": "1616588156.jpg",
        "image_title": "City",
        "user_id": 2,
        "updated_at": "2021-03-24 17:45:56",
        "created_at": "2021-03-24 17:45:56",
        "pic_id": 14
    },
    "message": "Image uploaded Successfully!"
 }
 }
```

code for above JSON service to add image and title to collectionview.. here i am saving `pic_id` like this in UserDefaults `UserDefaults.standard.set(picId, forKey: "pic_id")`

```
   fileprivate func postServiceCall(){
    
   if titleTextfield.text?.trim() == ""{
   return self.view.makeToast("please add service title")
   }
    let parameters = ["image_title" : titleTextfield.text?.trim() ?? ""]
    
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.uploadMultipartFormData(param: parameters, url: CommonUrl.edit_profile_images, image: imageProfile, fileName: "image", vc: self, isHeaderNeeded: true) {(responseData) in
        print("edit profile result \(responseData)")
            if let result = responseData.dict?["result"] as? NSDictionary{
                    let success = result["status"] as? [String : Any]
                    let message = success?["message"] as? String
                if message == "Success"{
                    let image = result["image"] as? [String : Any]
                    let picId = image?["id"]
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(picId, forKey: "pic_id")// here i am saving pic_id
                    self.arrImageItems.append(ImageItemModel(title: self.titleTextfield.text, imgTitle: self.imageProfile))
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                else{
                    self.view.makeToast(CommonMessages.somethingWentWrong)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**JSON service code for remove cell in collectionview**

```
@objc func deleteService(sender:UIButton) {
    let picId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pic_id")
    print("selected picid \(picId)")
    let param = ["pic_id" : picId]
    APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param as [String : Any], method: .post, loaderNeed: false, loadingButton: sender as! TransitionButton, needViewHideShowAfterLoading: nil, vc: self,?url: CommonUrl.edit_profile_images_remove, isTokenNeeded: true, isErrorAlertNeeded: true, isSuccessAlertNeeded: false, actionErrorOrSuccess: nil, fromLoginPageCallBack: nil) { [weak self] (resp) in
            if let code = ((resp.dict?["result"] as? [String : Any])){
                print("total result: \(code)")
                let success = code["status"] as? [String : Any]
                let message = success?["message"] as? String
                if message == "Success"{
                    let selectedIndex = sender.tag
                    self?.arrImageItems.remove(at: selectedIndex)
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()                    }
            }else{
                self?.view.makeToast(CommonMessages.somethingWentWrong)
            }
        }
}
```

**this is collectionview cellForItemAt code:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.imgView.image = arrImageItems[indexPath.item].profileImage
    cell.lblTitle.text = arrImageItems[indexPath.row].title
    cell.deleteButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteService(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

this is `ImageItemModel` model

```
class ImageItemModel{
var title: String?
var profileImage: UIImage?
var pic_id: String?

init(title: String?, imgTitle: UIImage?, pic_id: String?) {
    self.title = title
    self.profileImage = imgTitle
    self.pic_id = pic_id
}
}
```

with this above code i am able to delete only first time one cell.. if i am trying to delete one more cell then i am getting JSON validation error... how to delete selected cell all the time.. pls do help with code

Comment: can you send code of cellforItem at indexPath?

Comment: @Zain i have added the code.. pls guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing picture with same key in user defaults, which is wrong. it will only store last item of the loop.
You should add picID in your model inside postServiceCall method like this

```
self.arrImageItems.append(ImageItemModel(title: self.titleTextfield.text, imgTitle: self.imageProfile, picID: picId))
```

and then in deleteService method you need to get picID like this

```
let picId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "pic_id")//Replace this with this one
let picId = arrImageItems[sender.tag]. picID
```

Now everything will work fine.

Comment: @learn_swift i have update my answer please check. sorry i did not notice userdefault that you are using.